# IE 8 and WIndows 7 - always hangs when I try to print

Tags: internet, internet-explorer, printing

This is starting to become a pain. Whenever I try to print from a website, my IE 8 crashes! I have two Windows 7 machines that do this. They are both all up - to - date and both print to a shared printer that is connected to a windows 2003 standard server. Printer is connected to the server via usb and the model is a HP LaserJet P1005. IE is the only aplication that causes this to happen. Any ideas????

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue.  There's a very detailed troubleshooting guide [on the Microsoft answers site.](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/InternetExplorer/thread/26a41a21-cb3c-4769-843c-970f39db671e)

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Unfortunately I have tried all of this but to no avail. Here is what else I found out though. When I plug the printer in to my WIndows 7 machine via USB, IE8 prints web pages just fine. There is something with the driver as it is used with Windows 2003 as a print server that is causing this?? Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: I am pretty sure I got this fixed now. I deleted the printer on the work stations and the server. Reintalled the printer on the server and then reinstaled on all of the workstations. so far so good. I will let you know.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with sharing this printer on a network. Since it is a fairly in expensive HP printer and was not meant to really be networked it has been still causing me issues with IE and printing. (Firefox and anyother Windows program seems to be ok.) Since I really don't want to use Firefox (actually is is my wife who doesn't) and I am too cheap to buy a new printer, I have found the perfect work around and I thought I would share it with you. If you go to http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/winmacprinter/